# Why does "Android Keyboard" keep crashing even though I'm not using it?

Tags: swype

I use the Swype keyboard to enter text on my Samsung Galaxy S5 running Android 5.1.

Often, at least once a day and often more depending on usage, I get a pop up error message that says "Unfortunately Android Keyboard has stopped" and I have to click "Ok" to dismiss it. It does not seem to matter what app I'm using, this error will pop up any time I'm entering text.

I'm not using Android Keyboard, I'm using Swype, so why am I getting this error and how do I stop it from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing the cache and app data for keyboard.  Go to system settings then apps and search the keyboard there.  Try clearing cache and app data.  If the problem is still there you can disable the keyboard.

Mostly the default keyboard is Google Keyboard